# Infinite loop when button is clicked on Android

Tags: android, android-emulator

What I'm trying to do is:

If the EditText input is equal to the random number generated, then stop the loop otherwise keep on the loop and reset input text.

For some reason, I'm getting an infinite loop. I am new to programming, any help is really appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private TextView tvResult;
private TextView tvRandTest;
private EditText et1;
private String randonNumber;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

     tvResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
     tvRandTest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

     et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
}//End Main

public void myClickHandler(View view)
{               
    if(view.getId() == R.id.button1)
    {                                   
        //Generates 6 one digit Random Numbers
        int randonNumber1 =  (int) (0 + Math.random() * 9);

        //Parse Numbers             
        String rd1 = Integer.toString(randonNumber1);

        randonNumber = rd1;

    boolean done = false;       
    do          
        {   

        et1.getText().toString();
        if(et1.equals(randonNumber))
        {
            Toast.makeText(Main.this,"Equal Number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            tvResult.setText(randonNumber); 
             done = true;
        }//end if
      else
        { 
          Toast.makeText(Main.this,"Not Equal Number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          et1.setText("");

        }//end else

        }//End While
    while(!done);

    }//End if


     if(view.getId() == R.id.button2)

        {

             tvRandTest.setText(randonNumber);
        }


}//End Method

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO 
}
}//End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if(et1.equals(randonNumber))
```

I will change it with

```
 if(et1.equals(String.valueOf(randonNumber)))
```

you put directly the int value inside the equals method two things will happen:

1. the autboxing will create an Integer object starting from the int value
2. the `toString()` method will be called through this object.

the `toString()` method of Integer in android, as the doc stands:

```
Returns a string containing a concise, human-readable description of this object.
```

So you are compareing  the address of the new object with the content of et1 and not with its real value. [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Integer.html) the reference

Answer (score 0):

In this line `et1.getText().toString();` you need to assign result to variable, for example `String input = et1.getText().toString();` Then in next line you need to compare two strings, `if(input.equals(randonNumber))` But your program can hang cause of infinity loop on UI thread. You should use [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29)
to handle when text in EditText was changed